# Хочу писать под Android, но не люблю Java

Tags: java, android, android-ndk

Не люблю Java и все. А хочется писать именно под это платформу. Я знаю, что существует Android NDK, но его же надо использовать только по назначению для каких-либо серозных вещей типа движков для игр.

Comment: я вроде читал-в анрдюше можно на Си писать

Comment: Да, это <a href="http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html">AndroidNDK</a>, но там написано, что использовать стоит только по необходимости.

Comment: Жаль Вас:)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Тогда без Java! Для андроида можно разрабатывать приложения на *почти* любом языке программирования, компиляторы которых генерируют байт-код для JVM.

- Нравится функциональное программирование, совмещенное с продуманной объектной моделью? Развитая система типов? Тогда смотрите [Scala](http://scala-lang.org/) и краткую [инструкцию](http://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/scala-ide/Developing_for_Android) по разработке приложений на Scala для Android.
- Нравится функциональное программирование в совокупности с динамической типизацией? Макросы и идея семантической компрессии приводят вас в восторг? Тогда смотрите [Clojure](http://clojure.org/). Вот [так](http://riddell.us/ClojureAndAndroidWithEmacsOnUbuntu.html) его используют для разработки под Android.
- Фанат скриптовых языков? Выбирайте - [Ruby](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/) или [Python](http://python.org/), что больше нравится. [Здесь](http://www.thebitsource.com/programming-software-development/android/python-jruby-on-the-android-platform-in-10-steps/) объяснят, как их "готовить" для Android'а.

**Предупреждение**: конечно, на практике не все так идеально. Чтобы успешно разрабатывать на вышеперечисленных языках для платформы Android, потребуется вложить на первых порах намного больше сил, чем в случае с Java. Придется научиться использовать дополнительные инструменты, подыскать среды программирования, зачастую не такие удобные, как для Java, преодолеть свою лень и получше изучить "внутренности" виртуальных машин JVM и Dalvik, ну и т.д. Если осилите - о Java можно *почти полностью* забыть.

**Примечание о производительности**: из перечисленных Scala единственный язык со статической типизацией. Производительность почти такая же, как и у Java. Хотя идиоматический код на Scala может быть медленнее: чтобы понять почему, вам надо хорошо понимать, что такое функциональное программирование - это отдельная большая тема. Остальные языки - динамические, и как следствие, на порядок уступают в производительности Java. Хотелось бы, однако, напомнить, что "преждевременная оптимизация - корень всех зол". А также то, что фактор производительности излишне переоценивается программистами. Серверная часть многопользовательской онлайн-игры Eve Online, в которую одновременно играют десятки тысяч человек, написана на Python. Вы уверены, что требования вашего проекта к производительности выше, чем у разработчиков этой игры? В 95% случаев ответ отрицательный.

Comment: Ого!!! Спасибо большое. А как там у них с производительностью?

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста. Внес в ответ примечание о производительности.

Comment: Если бы можно было писать на Python, то я был бы просто счастлив. И мои глаза уже начали блестеть, когда я читал статью, которую Вы <a href="http://www.thebitsource.com/programming-software-development/android/python-jruby-on-the-android-platform-in-10-steps/">привели</a>. Но, к сожалению, люди пишут, что не доступен PIL (Python Imaging Library). А это очень грустно :(

Comment: А чем плох класс Bitmap (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html) из Android SDK? Вроде бы он тоже предоставляет методы для попиксельной обработки изображений. И не надо тянуть никаких сторонних библиотек.

Comment: Плох он тем, что я не знал о нем. Хотя, наверное, это все-таки не его вина, а моя. 

Спасибо большое. Будем пробовать.

Answer (score 1):

Если по каким-либо причинам вы не можете писать на Java, то у вас остается один выход - использовать каркасы, которые поставляют сторонние разработчики. Например, [Rhodes](http://rhomobile.com/products/rhodes/). Если выберете его, будете писать на HTML + JavaScript + Ruby, правда в возможностях будете сильно ограничены.

Comment: С Ruby как-тот не довелось сталкиваться. Я вот сейчас смотрю что из себя представляет Objective-J. Возможно это будет решением моей проблемы.

Answer (score 0):

Adobe Flex.

Comment: Я думаю тяжеловато будет его поднять под Debian :( Да и вообще Flash по-моему умирает.

Answer (score 0):

Lua любите? Пишите сразу и под Android, и под iOS: [Corona SDK](http://www.coronalabs.com/products/corona-sdk/)

Comment: Вы минусы не указали.
— лицензия $200-350/год (все вышеперечисленные средства бесплатны)
— невозможность подключать сторонние библиотеки, написанные не на Lua (скажем, модуль издателя игры или баннерной сети)
— критичный к быстродействию код все равно придется писать на Lua, если нет соответствующей функции в API движка, или искать обходные пути (они, как правило, есть)
— некоторые различия в функционале версий для Android и iOS (например, платежи внутри приложения поддерживаются пока только на iOS)

Comment: Я и плюсы не все перечислил : ) Что касается платности, не считаю минусом использование профессионального инструмента за деньги.

Спасибо за перечисленные детали, я глубоко не вникал в Corona пока, просто попробовал как-то.

Answer (score -1):

NativeActivity вам в помощь.